# Migrating Joomla! users to Magento without losing their passwords?

Tags: magento-1.9, database, migration, password

We have tried to migrate our old Joomla! users to our new Magento platform, all the user's information is migrated except their passwords!

Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: is joomla uses md5 for password?

Comment: i have no idea actually , but i think so..

Comment: if yes than you can update that md5 hash value directly into database. for that refer https://stuntcoders.com/snippets/magento-set-users-password-through-database/

Comment: No, Joomla has about 5 different ways to store passwords. Now I also faced with this problem and trying to solve it